# EF query, get usernames from friends that posted something

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i am building webapp similar to facebook. I want to query the database so i get the posts from the friends of the current logged in user(something similar to "home" from facebook)
Ok here are the models

```
public User()
    {
        this.Friends = new HashSet<Friend>();
        this.Friends1 = new HashSet<Friend>();
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int userID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid user_Unique_ID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profilePicUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }


public partial class Friend
{
    public int friendshipID { get; set; }
    public int userfrID { get; set; }
    public int friendID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Post
{
    public int postID { get; set; }
    public int userpostID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime postedOn { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int likes { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

What i tried is, creating a viewmodel:

```
public class HomePosts
{
    public int postID { get; set; }
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public int userpostID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime postedOn { get; set; }
    public int likes { get; set; }
    public int userfrID { get; set; }
    public int friendID { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my query:

```
using (var context = new ASPNETDBEntities())
        {
            MembershipUser x = Membership.GetUser();
            User wad = context.Users.Where(u => u.user_Unique_ID == (System.Guid)x.ProviderUserKey).SingleOrDefault();
            int id = wad.userID;
            var allposts = (from u in db.Users
                            join f in db.Friends
                            on u.userID equals f.userfrID
                            where f.userfrID == id
                            join p in db.Posts
                            on f.friendID equals p.userpostID
                            select new HomePosts
                            {
                                friendID = f.friendID,
                                likes = p.likes,
                                postedOn = p.postedOn,
                                postID = p.postID,
                                text = p.text,
                                userfrID = f.userfrID,
                                userID = u.userID,
                                username = u.username, <-- this is the problem
                                userpostID = p.userpostID
                            }).OrderByDescending(u => u.postedOn).ToList();
            return View(allposts);
        }
```

The problem is, for every post it shows the username of the current logged user, not the username from the friend that posted that post. I need the username of the poster(friend).
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, can you try this:

```
from f in db.Friends
join u in db.Users
on f.friendID equals u.userID  
where f.userfrId = id
join p in db.Posts                             
on f.friendID equals p.userpostID                             
select new HomePosts 
{                                 
    friendID = f.friendID,                                 
    likes = p.likes,                                 
    postedOn = p.postedOn,                                 
    postID = p.postID,                                 
    text = p.text,                                 
    userfrID = f.userfrID,                                 
    userID = u.userID,                                 
    username = u.username, 
    userpostID = p.userpostID                             
}
```

Alternatively if your EF is setup correctly you could do:

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.User.Any(u => u.Friends.Any(f => f.userfrID == id))).Select(p => new HomePosts 
    {                                 
        // your selections                          
    }

)
```

Comment: Ty, the first one is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this part

```
join p in db.Posts    
on f.friendID equals p.userpostID
```

be:

```
join p in db.Posts
on u.userID equals p.userpostID
```

?

Unless I'm misenterpreting, it sounds like what you have says:

join the posts table on the post's user id --> current user --> friend --> friend id (which loops back to the current user)